# Exporting Objects with the Exports Object

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

Say I have one `.js` file containing a javascript object. I want to be able to access that object and all of its functionality from another `.js` file in the same directory. Can I simply export this object with the `module.exports` object and `require()` it in the other `.js` file? If this is possible can you give me an example?

If it helps I'm developing with node.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the way I create modules:

myModule.js

```
var MyObject = function() {

    // This is private because it is not being return
    var _privateFunction = function(param1, param2) {
        ...
        return;
    }

    var function1 = function(param1, callback) {
        ...
        callback(err, results);    
    }

    var function2 = function(param1, param2, callback) {
        ...
        callback(err, results);    
    }

    return {
        function1: function1
       ,function2: function2
    }
}();

module.exports = MyObject;
```

And to use this module in another JS file, you can simply use `require` and use your object as normal:

someFile.js

```
var myObject = require('myModule');

myObject.function1(param1, function(err, result) { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: So if, in node, I do not return the functions at the end of the object definition, I won't be able to access the (private) functions? even if I require the module?

Comment: Correct, you wont be able to access them via the object.  `myObject._privateFunction(p1,p2)` will throw an error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_privateFunction'`

Answer (score 11):

Of course you can. In my example I use obj to hold my config info. I put it in a file called `index.js` in `config` folder. This makes the index the preferred choice to be picked when I `import 'config'`. I have 2 exports here one for my node and api stuff and the other for my db. You can ignore the first bit where I set the environment.

```
const environment = {
  development: {
    isProduction: false
  },
  production: {
    isProduction: true
  }
}[ process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development' ];

export default Object.assign({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  remoteApi: {
    token: {
      'X-Token': '222222222222222222'
    },
    base: 'https://www.somedomain.com/api'
  }
}, environment);

export const db = {
  dbHost: 'localhost',
  dbPort: 176178
};
```

Calling `import config from '../config';` will pick the default one. And if I specify I can get the `db` export `import { db } from '../config';`

Comment: How to use particular `import { db } from '../config'` in require??

Answer (score 5):

In one file:

```
module.exports.myObj = some object...;
```

In the other:

```
Obj = require('myFile.js').myObj;
```

Everything in a js file on node is local to that file unless you put it in the export object. This actually is very different from JavaScript in a browser--in the browser all files that get imported act together like one big file.

You can kinda think about node files as though you are creating a module object and passing it' into a function surrounding your code.

```
module = { 'exports' : {} };
(function(module){
    //your js file
    ...
})(module)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can Export object in JavaScript like this

```js
// global/styles.js

export const borderStyles = {
  border: "2px solid black",
  color : "#000"
};
```

and you can import it like the following

```js
import { borderStyles } from "../../global/styles"
```

Answer (score 2):

the simplest approach, in my opinion:

write Person.js: (note it comes with ctor)

```
module.exports = function (firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = function () { 
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

and consume it:

```
var person = require('./Person.js');

var person1 = new person('James', 'Bond');

console.log(person1.fullName());
```

note that in this simple solution all methods are "public".

ref: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

Answer (score 2):

as per es6 :-

```
const person = function(name){
  console.log(`Name of the person is ${name}`);
}

export default person;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export object like

**modules.js**

```
export const events = {};
events.click = function (param1, param2...) {
    //do something here
}
events.change = function (param1, param2...) {
    //do something here
}
events.get = function (key, response) {
    //do something here
    response({status: "success"})
}
```

In **main.js**

```
import {events} from "./modules"
console.log(events)
```

Now you can use the Objects

```
events.get("my_key", (resp) => { 
  console.log(resp) // {status: "success"}
})
```